# How to wrap (to group) a list of elements into another element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure.

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Can I convert it into:

```
<uL>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

So the task is to group li into "rows". There are always 3 li in 1 row, but row number is always different.

Does someone know, how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `wrapAll`:

```
var a = $('li');
do $(a.slice(0,3)).wrapAll('<ul />');   
while((a = a.slice(3)).length>0)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/mZr4h/

Answer (score 4):

```
var i, num = 3, $ul = $('#ul'), $li = $('#ul > li');
for (i=0;i<$li.length;i+=num) {
    $li.slice(i,i+num).wrapAll('<ul />');
}
$ul.find('> ul').unwrap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2bYz/

Answer (score 1):

[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) api is what you are looking for

Comment: I know this, but I don't know how to get each 3 elements and to wrap them in ul. Could you write an example, please?

Comment: `wrap()` is infact not what he is looking for, he is looking for `wrapAll()`