# JQuery: How to select element by group from selected element until the other selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say we have the list of following heading:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>

<h2>Heading</h2>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h4>Heading</h4>

<h5>Heading</h5>
<h6>Heading</h6>

<h2>Heading</h2>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h4>Heading</h4>

<h5>Heading</h5>
<h6>Heading</h6>
```

How would I select the elements from `<h2>-<h4>` then wrap them on a `<fieldset>` element by group?
That would have 2 groups wrapped by fieldset.

I tried the code below but it don't work as I expected.

```
jQuery('h2').nextUntil('h4');
```

**What selector and function would work?**

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried. Plus, this is quite trivial. Go read up on .wrap(), .wrapInner(), and .wrapAll().

Comment: Someone forgot how to Google: http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451781/how-to-wrap-to-group-a-list-of-elements-into-another-element-with-jquery

Comment: @j08691, Sorry, already edited my post

Comment: Hi, I already edited the post. I just wanted to know what selector would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('h2,h3,h4').wrapAll('<fieldset>');
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Just curious how could I select by group if theres a series of h2-h4 then another set of h2-h4 and so forth?

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm rushing: `$('h2').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h4+*').addBack().wrapAll('<fieldset>');
});`   Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/hh3v7qwg/

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. Noted that addBack function.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery:

```
$( "h2, h3, h4" ).wrapAll( "<fieldset></fieldset>" );
```